# Pretty photo not working: "prettyPhoto is not a function"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, prettyphoto

I'm trying to setup PrettyPhoto on a wordpress site.

Example of page that loads script: http://kaarma.pixelworklab.com/quick-pay/

This is one of the errors output in firefox console:

```
[cycle] terminating; zero elements found by selector

jquery...test.js (line 27)

TypeError: $("a[href$='.jpg'], a[href$='.jpeg'], a[href$='.gif'], a[href$='.png']").prettyPhoto is not a function
[Break On This Error]   

showTitle: true /* true/false */
```

Basically when you click on the images (bottom 3) they open in a new screen and never trigger prettyPhoto..

Any ideas greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PrettyPhoto javascript and CSS files are not loaded, you have specified wrong urls

- http://**kaarma.pixelworklab.comLIBRARIES_URIprettyPhoto**/css/prettyPhoto.css?ver=3.4.1
- http:/**/kaarma.pixelworklab.comLIBRARIES_URIprettyPhoto**/js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js?ver=3.4.1